# Easier Installation of privatenode for non-technical users

Tags: private-blockchain, dapps

I have seen documentation of creating privatenet using geth. But it holds few commands which will not be a better option for users/clients who doesn't have technical knowledge to use the application in privatenet. It is not expected that each user will run geth commands on terminal. Creating docker is the efficient solution for such situations?

Answer (score 0):

you can do one thing:

> You firstly setup private node on aws for the client and connect the
>   application to this aws private node so the client does not require to
>   run geth terminal on own.

Hope this will help you.